# v8 C++ Api: pass non-English strings from JavaScript to c++

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

In my c++ code I have:

```
Handle<ObjectTemplate> globalTemplate = ObjectTemplate::New();
globalTemplate->Set( String::New("print"), FunctionTemplate::New( printMessage ));
Handle<Context> context = Context::New( NULL, globalTemplate );
```

The printMessage function is defined as:

```
Handle<Value> printMessage(const Arguments& args) 
{
    Locker locker;
    HandleScope scope;

    if( args.Length() ) 
    {
        String::Utf8Value message( args[0]->ToString() );

        if( message.length() ) 
        {
            //Print the message to stdout
            printf( "%s", *message );

            bool newline = true;
            if(args.Length() == 2) 
            {
                newline = args[1]->ToBoolean()->BooleanValue();
            }

            if(newline) printf("\n");

            return scope.Close( Boolean::New( true ) );
        }
    } 

    return Undefined();
}
```

when I call this function from JavaScript:

```
print("Привет");
```

I see "пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ" instead of string.

What was wrong with this code?

Comment: is your console set up properly to display unicode?  It may be better to manually inspect the integral values of the bytes you're looking at instead of printing them out to verify if the data is correct and the display of the data isn't what you're expecting or if the raw data is actually wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks correct, so as @xaxxon suggested, I'd double-check that the terminal you use for output can deal with non-ASCII characters, and that the input file (if any) is encoded correctly.

Also, your V8 versions appears to be pretty old (e.g. the `HandleScope` constructor always takes an `Isolate*` parameter these days), so it's also possible that you're experiencing some old bug that has since been fixed.

For reference, the [official sample shell](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/samples/shell.cc#138) does things almost the same way, and on my machine at least works fine with your test string:

```
void Print(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
  bool first = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < args.Length(); i++) {
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(args.GetIsolate());
    if (first) {
      first = false;
    } else {
      printf(" ");
    }
    v8::String::Utf8Value str(args[i]);
    const char* cstr = ToCString(str);
    printf("%s", cstr);
  }
  printf("\n");
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: yes, I use an old code because of final size of exe file (I have about 2mb compared to 8mb with latest sources).